# RegisterMapping complains about "More than one export was found"?

Tags: wpf, telerik, prism, mef

I'm using `Prism` v4 and `MEF` together with `Telerik RadDocking`. In order to use `Prism` and `MEF` together with these docking panes, a custom adapter is needed. I have a working adapter which is exported as follows:

```
[Export]
public class RadPaneGroupRegionAdapter : RegionAdapterBase<RadPaneGroup>
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public RadPaneGroupRegionAdapter(IRegionBehaviorFactory regionBehaviorFactory)
        : base(regionBehaviorFactory)
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

I configure the aggregate catalogs in the bootstrapper as follows:

```
protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
{
    this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Bootstrapper).Assembly));
    this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog("Modules"));
    this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(ViewModelLocator).Assembly));
    this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(MyContractClass).Assembly));
}
```

### Prism complains about multiple exports?

The problem is that when I try to add this adapter to the `Prism` adapter mappings, I get an [ImportCardinalityMismatchException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.importcardinalitymismatchexception.aspx) telling me that *"More than one export was found that matches the constraint: xxx.Adapters.RadPaneGroupRegionAdapter"*

```
protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
{
    RegionAdapterMappings mappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
    mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(RadPaneGroup),
        this.Container.GetExportedValue<Adapters.RadPaneGroupRegionAdapter>());

    return mappings;
}
```

I cannot understand why this happens. **The adapter class is in the same assembly as the bootstrapper**, so I would expect there to be only one matching export.

**Please help!**

### UPDATE:

If I comment out this line, the exception is never thrown:

```
this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(MyContractClass).Assembly));
```

Maybe the problem is that `MyContractClass` is dependent on the same `Telerik` controls? If that is the case, how would I solve this ambiguity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that there are more than one candidates for the import and MEF cannot decide which one to use. There are two ways of dealing with such a problem:

One is to update your constructor to take a sequence of `IRegionBehaviorFactory` and add the [ImportManyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.importmanyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Of course you will have to decide which factory to keep.

```
[ImportingConstructor]
        public RadPaneGroupRegionAdapter([ImportMany]IEnumerable<IRegionBehaviorFactory> regionBehaviorFactory)
            : base(regionBehaviorFactory)
        {
            //Decide which factory to keep.
        }
```

The other would be to use a [FilteredCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.filteredcatalog.aspx) and ... filter the parts. You can read this article on [filtering catalogs](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Filtering%20Catalogs).

Both approaches will be more efficient if you add [export metadata](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata&referringTitle=Guide).